# Header DIV Layer Position Error in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, html, header, cross-browser

I'm having some problems with IE compatibility with my website. I currently have it parked at **http://www.verdasconews.com/tiago** while I test everything. I like to make sure I have compatibility with the major browsers. It looks fine in Firefox, Chrome, Opera & Safari, but in IE, I'm having problems with the header/content div layers.

Here's a screenshot of what it looks like in IE
https://i.stack.imgur.com/GOaSX.png

The post and sidebar content are overlapping the header when they should be tucked underneath, the way it appears in the other browsers.

This is the css for the positioning:

```
/*  ------ layout ------------------------ */ 

wrapper {
 background:url(img/back2.png) no-repeat center top; 
}  
contents { 
width:959px; 
margin:0 auto; 
text-align:left; 
}  
header { 
background:url(img/top.png) no-repeat bottom; 
height:160px; 
}  
middle-contents { 
background:url(img/side.png) repeat-y; 
padding-bottom:50px; 
}  
left-col { 
float:left; 
display:inline; 
width:584px; 
margin:0 0 0 5px; 
}  
right-col { 
float:right; 
display:inline; 
width:330px;
margin:15px 5px 0 0; 
}  
footer { 
background:url(img/bottom.png) no-repeat top; 
height:114px; 
margin-bottom:50px; 
}
```

and this is what my header positioning is

```
/*  ------ header ---------------------- */  
logo_image {
 margin:6px 0 0 4px; 
float:left; 
display:inline; 
}  
logo_image h1 { 
margin:0; 
padding:0; 
}
```

Not sure if the title is exactly right, as I asked a friend who thought that might've been the problem and a google search led me here. I'm not a pro with programming, but I'm hoping someone who is can sort out what might be wrong here. I can provide the full css if necessary. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can fix it by removing height:160 from #header, and also remove float:left and display:inline from #logo_image